# Assignment of function template instantiation to function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++20

Please consider the following C++20 program:

```
void (*p)(int x);

void f(auto x) {
    p = f;
}

int main() {
    f(4.2);
}
```

Is this ill-formed?  What I would have expected to happen is that `f(4.2)` instantiates `f` as `void(double)`, and so the assignment of p to f should be a type mismatch.  But, g++ accepts this without warning.

What am I missing?

**Update**

For reference, the following program:

```
void (*p)(int x);

void g(double x);

int main() {
    p = g;
}
```

fails with error: invalid conversion from `void (*)(double)` to `void (*)(int)`

Comment: Probably implicit type conversion from double to int?

Comment: @SumnerEvans: A function pointer of type `void(*)(double)` implicitly converts to a function pointer of type `void(*)(int)` ?

Comment: @SumnerEvans: see update.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Now I'm seriously confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the assignment of p to f should be a type mismatch

No, `p = f;` causes the instantiation of `void(int)`, then it's assigned to `p`.

Comment: Ok, so `f` names the function template and not the current instantiation.  So there are two instantiations of f in the program.  That makes sense.  Is there a way to refer to the current instantiation?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos You can use `static_cast` to specify the instantiation like `p = static_cast<void(*)(decltype(x))> (f);`, then you'll get the error.

Comment: Ok, interesting, so I guess `decltype(f)` won't work either because again `f` will refer to the function template and not the current instantiation?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yes, and compilers can't know which instantiation should be used.

Comment: Well I guess the language could offer a way to refer to the current instantiation of a function template (like it does with the injected class name of a class template), I guess it just doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yes, AFAIK injected name works only for class (template).